# What is the reason for not receiving the email notification for receiving recommendations for Sitecore MVP this year?

Tags: community, mvp

Sitecore used to send an email notification to recommending someone for Sitecore MVP. But this year, they have stopped sending the confirmation email. Is there any specific reason for this?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this has been discussed on Slack and I don't think we should import that here as SSE is not a discussion platform.

Comment: The question is to the point, I don't see how it's off topic given there are other questions regarding the MVP program.

Comment: I agree that importing a discussion is not necessary, it should only have the answer, however this is an answer that can only be answered by Sitecore and could not definitively be answered by the community. I therefore suggest that Rohit contact the MVP Program email inbox to ask this question.

Comment: Thanks, Jay. I agree and will ask the question. I will add the answer based on that for benefits for others.

Comment: Perhaps this rephrased question will give you the answers you seek. https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/8674/what-should-i-expect-in-the-mvp-nomination-or-first-time-application-process